# Class methods and SOLID principles in PHP

Tags: php, solid-principles

Let's imagine we have a Class called Register, This class only Registers user and shows a message if validation doesn't pass.

```
 class Register {

        function register_user() {

            // Do Validation, Get message and Show it if faild
            ...
            $message = $this->get_message( $error_code );
            ...


            // Register User Codes
            ...

        }


        // Some other related methods
        ...


        function get_message( $error_code ) {

            // Returns **different messages** based on error code.

        }

  }
```

My question is this: Should get message be a part of Register class, Or should it have its own class for handling messages for Register, Login, ForgotPassword... ?

Which one is more SOLID friendly?

Comment: But here's another question: why would you have a class just for registering? Wouldn't it make more sense to make your class more like user service that has register, login, forgot password, ... methods?

Comment: @Mikey Having all those methods in one class is obviously not SOLID (single responsibility principle fails)

Answer (score 2):

In a good OOP implementation you would create a user class with functions (methods) like register, login, logout, display_user, modify_user, and more functions. Your object is the user. Having a class with only a register_user function, another class with only a login_user function, would complicate your code for no reasons and goes against basic OOP. I don't know much about SOLID but you can certainly make individual functions safe and robust by using modifiers like private, protected, final and more.

Comment: Stephane having a giant class with tons of methods is wrong because it fails at so many levels. Tight-Coupling, Un-Testability and Maintenance nightmare is just some examples.

This may work for a tiny application or module, But when working on a big project which other developers are involved too and the application is always growing and changing, it will fail.

SOLID principles are there too assure that we would avoid common pitfalls and code smells, and have a easy to maintain and extend code.

Comment: Yes I certainly agree with you that giant classes are not good software design practice, but having 1 method per class like in the question neither because it is like going back to procedural programming and this is not the goal of SOLID.